# Converting color bitmap to grayscale image using only the blue channel using a colormatrix

Tags: android, bitmap, grayscale, colormatrix

I need to grayscale a bitmap in Android using only the blue color channel.
I managed to get rid of the green and red channels by using a colormatrix, but when I set the saturation of that matrix to 0 it is ignoring the previously made changes to the red and green channels.

Is there a way to accomplish my task? Iterating through the whole pixel array is not an option as it is way too slow.

I'm using this piece of code:

```
public Bitmap ConvertToGrayscale(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int height = super.getHeight();
    int width = super.getWidth();

    float[] arrayForColorMatrix = new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                               0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                               0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

    Bitmap.Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
    Bitmap grayScaleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(grayScaleBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(arrayForColorMatrix);
    matrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    paint.setColorFilter(filter);

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    return grayScaleBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct matrix for getting a gray scaled image from the blue channel is the following:

```
float[] arrayForColorMatrix = new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                           0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                           0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                           0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
```

[From the Android documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html)

> When applied to a color [r, g, b, a], the resulting color is computed as (after clamping):

```
R' = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e;
G' = f*R + g*G + h*B + i*A + j;
B' = k*R + l*G + m*B + n*A + o;
A' = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t;
```

Using my `arrayForColorMatrix` I get the blue value for every value of the RGB color components, which results in a gray scaled bitmap based on the blue channel.